# the_content doesn't return <p> tags

Tags: themes

I'm using a piece of code that returns all of my pages on 1 page (custom theme). The code works perfectly, but I can't manage to output the pages with any `<p>` tags or formatting.

```
$pages = get_pages(); 

foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
    $title = $page_data->post_title; 
    echo $content; 
}
```

I've read that you can use `get_the_content`, but I don't see how I can implement this in my loop.

Comment: do you have all plugins disabled, do you disable autop, is it possible that you run this code before the init?

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.

1.

```
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    echo wpautop( $content ); 
}
```

2.

```
$pages = get_pages();

if(!empty($pages)) {
  echo "<p>"
  foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    echo $content;
  }
  echo "<p>"
}
```